# why cannot I keep all varibles in the list when while loop is running

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

```
while not endgame:

        cardsOnTable = OnTable()

        faceUp1 = player1.dequeue()
        cardsOnTable.place('player1',faceUp1,False)

        faceUp2 = player2.dequeue()
        cardsOnTable.place('player2',faceUp2,False)


        print(str(cardsOnTable))
        size1 = player1.size()
        size2 = player2.size()
        print('Player1 : '+str(size1),'Player2 : '+str(size2))

        result = compareCard(faceUp1,faceUp2)
                   elif result == 0:
            print('WAR STARTS!!!')


                i = 0
                player1war = [] #a list for placing player1's card in war(cards on table)
                player2war = [] #a list for placing player2's card in war(cards on table)

                while i < nbWarCards:
                    faceDown1 = player1.dequeue()
                    player1war.append(faceDown1)
                    faceDown2 = player2.dequeue()
                    player2war.append(faceDown2)

                    i += 1

                for card in player1war:
                    cardsOnTable.place('player1',card,True)

                player1war.clear()

                for card in player2war:
                    cardsOnTable.place('player2',card,True)

                player2war.clear()

                            if player1.size() == 0 or player2.size() == 0:
            endgame = True
```

my problem happens when I tried to `print(str(cardOnTable))` when the first time this while loop runs, it will give me `[AS | AH]`, that's what I want. However, when this while loop runs second time, it is supposed to print `[A3 XX XX XX AS | AH XX XX XX A5]`,it only prints `[A3 | A5]`.

this is my `class OnTable()`:

```
class OnTable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cards = []
        self.__faceUp = []


    def place(self,player,card,hidden):

        if player == 'player2':
            self.__cards.append(card)
            if hidden == False:
                self.__faceUp.append(False)
            elif hidden == True:
                self.__faceUp.append(True)
        elif player == 'player1':
            self.__cards.insert(0,card)
            if hidden == False:
                self.__faceUp.insert(0,False)
            elif hidden == True:
                self.__faceUp.insert(0,True)            

        #return self.__cards   
    def cleanTable(self):
        self.__cards.clear()
        self.__faceUp.clear()    


    def __str__(self):

        for i in range(len(self.__faceUp)):
            if self.__faceUp[i] == True:
                self.__cards[i] = 'XX'

        list1 = '['
        for item in self.__cards:
            list1 += (str(item)+' ')

        list1 = re.sub(' ', ' ', list1.strip())
        half = int(len(list1)//2)      
        list1 = list1[:half] + ' |' + list1[half:]

        return list1 + ']'
```

I tried to track my code, and I found `self.__cards` have all variables before second time the `player1.dequeue()`, then it loses all the previous variables.

Could someone please tell how to fix this problem? Thank you

Comment: Please fix your indentation (first section of code), it is very hard to help unless you present code that is correctly indented.

Comment: I think it's because you are creating a new instance of the class at every iteration. Try putting that `cardsOnTable = OnTable()` before entering the `while not endgame` loop. It's a very quick read, so there might be more to it.

Comment: yeah, you are right, I am supposed to put ontable() outside of while loop. Thank you...